# Is IntroSpection Endpoint needed for JWT token?

Tags: oauth-2.0, identityserver4

As the JWT token is self-contained, it can be validated locally in the resource server and the resource does not need to send the token to the IdentityServer IntroSpection Endpoint for validation.

I check the implementation of the [IdentityServer4.AccessTokenValidation](https://github.com/IdentityServer/IdentityServer4.AccessTokenValidation), it validate the JWT token locally if the IdentityServerAuthenticationOptions is set to support JWT.  The only way to use the IntroSpection endpoint for the JWT token is setting the IdentityServerAuthenticationOptions to support reference only.

Is there any special case that need to send the JWT access token to the IntroSpection Endpoint?

For the resource server that does not have the cryptographic abilities locally, should it have got the reference token, instead of the JWT token?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

JWTs are typically validated locally on the resource server.

It's a technical detail that IdentityServer can also validate JWTs at the introspection endpoint. That could be used e.g. when the resource server does not have an appropriate JWT library (and you don't want to store reference tokens on the IS side).

Answer (score 0):

As per my knowledge, introspection endpoint can be used either independently or with JWT.

These are the two possible scenarios for authentication:

- Only JWT: I only use JWT for authentication.
- Both JWT and introspection endpoint: Here I use JWT for providing core information (like issuer info) and the introspection endpoint for providing more fine tuned information which needs an additional level of security (like client info, scopes info etc).